# How to inject the array indices of objects in an array into the objects, using jq

Tags: indexing, jq

Given an array of objects, I would like to inject a property with its position in the array. 
For example:

```
[ { "w" : "Hello" }, { "w" : "World } ]
```

I would like to produce:

```
[ { "w" : "Hello", p: 0 }, { "w" : "World, p:1 } ]
```

where p is the zero-based position in the array.

Is there a way to get the index of the element?
I tried this but it is not working:

```
    keys[] as $i | [ .[] | .p= $i ]
```

I get:

```
 [ { "w" : "Hello", p: 0 }, { "w" : "World, p:0 } ]
```

Comment: I think I got it: `to_entries | map({name:.value, index:.key}) | [ .[] | .name.p=.index ] | [ .[] | .name ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
[ keys[] as $i | .[$i] | .p=$i ]
```

Alternatively, you could make it work using `to_entries` like this:

```
[ to_entries[] | (.value.p=.key).value ]
```

Both of which yields:

```
[
  {
    "w": "Hello",
    "p": 0
  },
  {
    "w": "World",
    "p": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Awesome! Much simpler than my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses `reduce`

```
reduce keys[] as $i (.; .[$i].p = $i)
```